# Persistent retries via Spring Boot ActiveMQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am trying to configure persistent redeliveries via ActiveMQ 5.14.2 using Spring Boot but it just ignores part of my configuration.

According to the http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html (the last statement in the doc) I added `schedulerSupport="true"` within the `broker` element inside apache-activemq-5.14.2/conf/activemq.xml so it now looks like this:

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" schedulerDirectory="${activemq.data}/scheduler" schedulerSupport="true" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">
```

I also added a redelivery policy:

```
<plugins>
    <redeliveryPlugin fallbackToDeadLetter="true"
                      sendToDlqIfMaxRetriesExceeded="true">
        <redeliveryPolicyMap>
            <redeliveryPolicyMap>
                <redeliveryPolicyEntries>
                    <!-- a destination specific policy -->
                    <redeliveryPolicy queue="payments"
                                      maximumRedeliveries="10"
                                      redeliveryDelay="10000"/>
                </redeliveryPolicyEntries>

                <defaultEntry>
                    <!-- the fallback policy for all other destinations -->
                    <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="10"
                                      initialRedeliveryDelay="0"
                                      redeliveryDelay="10000"/>
                </defaultEntry>
            </redeliveryPolicyMap>
        </redeliveryPolicyMap>
    </redeliveryPlugin>
</plugins>
```

Inside my spring-boot application, I added config as shown below:

```
@Bean
public RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = connectionFactory.getRedeliveryPolicy();
    redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(10);
    redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(10000);
    redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(0);
    redeliveryPolicy.setUseExponentialBackOff(false);
    connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
    return redeliveryPolicy;
}
```

The problem is that whenever an exception is thrown in my application - ActiveMQ retries to resend the message 10 times (just as I specified) but it completely ignores redelivery delay, so it makes 10 redeliveries without a delay.

**The question is how to configure ActiveMQ to use redelivery delay.**

Comment: works for me...